# How can I open a csv file in python, and read one line at a time, without loading the whole csv file in memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, generator, yield

I have a csv file of size that would not fit in the memory of my machine. So I want to open the csv file and then read it's rows one at a time. I basically want to make a python generator that yields single rows from the csv.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open(filename, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        doanything()
```

Python is lazy whenever possible. File objects are generators and do not load the entire file but only one line at a time.

Comment: one more question, if you have worked with amazon s3. 

I am trying to read a csv from amazon s3, what additional steps to i need to take in order to achieve the same results.

Comment: I have never worked with amazon s3 but maybe that would be a topic for a seperate question anyway?

Comment: yes i found the solution.

thanks for the reply anyway :D

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**
You can use `chunksize` param available in pandas read_csv function

```
chunksize = 10 ** 6
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    print(type(chunk))
    # CODE HERE
```

set `chunksize` to 1 and it should take care of your problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

My personal preference for doing this is with [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

You set it up as an object, with pointers/parameters, and then to access the file one row at a time, you just iterate over it with `next` and it returns a dictionary containing the named field key, value pairs in your csv file.

e.g.

```
import csv
csvfile = open('names.csv')
my_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

first_row = next(my_reader)

for row in my_reader:
    print ( [(k,v) for k,v in row.items() ] )

csvfile.close()
```

See the linked docs for parameter usage etc - it's fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

*python generator that yields single rows from the csv.*

This sounds like you want [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) from built-in `csv` module. You will get one list for each line in file.